# Problem updating Google Contact Picture in Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api

I am trying to write a ruby app to update Google Contact Photos but I cant get the upload working.  Im not sure if I have misunderstood the Google API but this is what I have so far:

```
Net::HTTP.start(URI.parse(image_element.attributes['href']).host) do |http|
  response, body = http.put(URI.parse(image_element.attributes['href']).path, data, {'If-Match' => '*', 'content-type'=>'image/*'})
end
```

The Google Data API says:

> Every contact has a photo link
>   element. It has the form:
>
> href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/liz%40gmail.com/c9012de'
>   gd:etag='"KTlcZWs1bCp7ImBBPV43VUV4LXEZCXERZAc."'>
>
> That element appears whether the
>   contact has an associated photo or
>   not. If the contact does have a photo,
>   then the element contains a gd:etag
>   attribute specifying an ETag for the
>   photo. If the contact has no photo,
>   then there's no gd:etag attribute, and
>   the href attribute provides the URL to
>   use to add a photo to the contact.
>
> To add or update a photo given the
>    element shown above, send a new
>   photo with a PUT command to the URL:
>   https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/liz%40gmail.com/c9012de.
>   Remember to set a proper "image/*"
>   Content-Type header.
>
> To delete a photo, send an HTTP DELETE
>   request to the same URL.
>
> When updating or deleting a photo,
>   send the photo's ETag in the If-Match
>   header of the HTTP request.
>   Alternatively, use If-Match: * to
>   update or delete regardless of whether
>   you have the latest version of the
>   photo.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

UPDATE AND ANSWER:
I've managed to get this working with some help from StackOverflow and a mate. Basically what was wrong was the incorrect MIME type being set (see below) but also I wasn't authenticated properly with Google for the PUT request.  What I was trying to write was a Script that updates any missing Google Contact Photos with images from Gravatar (where possible).  Once I got it working it worked great: managed to match about 2 - 3 dozen contacts.  I wrote a blog post on the script in case anyone wants to run it also: http://ashleyangell.com/2011/06/ruby-script-to-import-google-contact-photos-from-gravatar/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used the Google Data API myself, but try setting the Content-Type header to, for example, `image/jpeg`, rather than just `image/*`.

Comment: This was a problem, but it wasn't the only problem. I've now fixed the script and it works great.