# How to update Google Contact's photo via PHP?

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am coding a site in PHP that will allow a user to view all his Google Contacts' names and profile photos in one long list. Then the user can drag-n-drop new photos to replace the existing profile photos.

**However, I'm getting a 401 (unauthorized access) error when trying to update the photos.**

I know the access_token is correct because it works in GET requests such as https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/6f2?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZR_ZS7_u-8TbMOMaeaGW9q4F7tkuPxW6gFTulyBX

The [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html#AddUpdating_photo) have not helped much. See also [these](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/using_cURL.html#updating-entries) and [these](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html).

My code looks something like:

```
#the stuff that i echo out is just for debugging purposes
$apiVersion='3.0';
$access_token = $this->session->userdata('googleauth_access_token');

$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/' . $contactID;
$fp = fopen($image_location, "r");
$filesize = filesize($image_location);
echo '<img src="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/'. $contactID. '?access_token=' . $access_token.'"/><br/>';    
echo $image_location;
echo $filesize;
echo $url;
$requestHeaders=array('Content-type: image/*','If-Match: '.$eTag,'GData-Version: '.$apiVersion);
$requestHeaders[]='Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token;
print_r($requestHeaders);
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $filesize);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
$result = curl_exec($c);    
$curlGetInfo=curl_getinfo($c);
print_r($curlGetInfo);
curl_close($c);
fclose($fp);
echo $result;
```

I have also tried variations such as replacing the `'Authorization: Bearer'` line with `Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=ya29.AHES6ZR_ZS7_u-8TbMOMaeaGW9q4F7tkuPxW6gFTulyBX`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe it worked, but changing `image/*` to `image/jpg` fixed the 401 error problem.

([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151034/problem-updating-google-contact-picture-in-ruby/6272056#6272056) tipped me off.)

Also FYI, I'm still using `$requestHeaders[]='Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token;` rather than `$requestHeaders[]='Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='. $access_token;`